# i want to display form 1 data in form 2 but the form appears blank

Tags: c#, forms

i am tring to get input in form 1 and output in form2  and similarly inout in form2 and output in fom1. but when i debug my code the form appears blank. it is not showing any text box or buttons. i have made form1 as a parent
Form 1 Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static String s;
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i, n, sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            f2.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text = s + Environment.NewLine;
            sum += Int32.Parse(s);
        }
         textBox1.Text+="sum="+sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2 Code

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.s = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that is awful. You might get somewhere if you instantiate a new form2 inside your loop, but you are not practicing any good design practices here, Not one.

Comment: Why the heck is s static, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a starter
In particular setting f1's TextBox1 is a bit untidy. 
In Form2 add a property.

```
Public int Value {get {return Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text); }
```

Make button1 an OK button (set modalresult to mrkOK)

In Form1 get rid of s and f2

the change your button1 click handler to

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int i, n, sum = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
  using(Form2 f2 = new Form2())
  {
    if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
      {
        TextBox1.Text = f2.Value.ToString();
      }
      else
      {
        TextBox1.Text = String.Concat(TextBox1.Text,Environment.NewLine,f2.Value.ToString());
      } 
      sum += f2.Value;
    }
  } 
  textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}sum={2}",TextBox1.Text, Environment.NewLine,sum);
}
```